# The infimum of the radii of convergence of a real analytic function over a compact

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is real analytic on a domain $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq1$. By definition at each point $x$ of $D$ the Taylor series expansion of $f$ converges; let $r(x)$ be the radius of convergence of this series. Again, by definition, $r(x)$ is never zero as $x$ runs over $D$. Now, let $K$ be a compact of $D$. Prove that the infimum of these $r(x)$, as $x$ runs over $K$ is strictly positive.

Comment: It's a compact set. Can you show $r(x)$ is continuous? Continuous functions achieve their extrema on compact sets, and the minimum is greater than zero so the infimum = minimum is as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would you do that?

Comment: Depends on what tools you have. Given you have a complex analysis tag: The radius of convergence is simply the distance to the nearest singularity. The distance function is necessarily continuous (e.g., since $\mathbb C$ has norm $|z|$)

Comment: Thanks. I will try...

Comment: Success I hope?